# Cors в Яндекс.Браузере

Tags: cors

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как отключить CORS в яндекс.браузере?

Пробую через флаги для хрома, в итоге безуспешно.

Comment: Не надо его отключать

Comment: надо) кто тебе это сказал?

Comment: Здравый смысл сказал, CORS существует не просто так